# Char array, string represents a memory address how can i add value to that address?

Tags: c

I have a char array that holds a memory address for example
    char add[8]="000AAC88";
I want to put a character into the memory address specified by the add array , in other words I want to have a character for example 'a' in the memory address of 000AAC88 
This will be done in C

Comment: Try `*(char *) 0x000AAC88 = 'a';` If you still have your `add` [as described], you'd need to use `unsigned long val = strtol(add,NULL,16);` on it to get the _decoded_ value and do `*(char *) val = 'a';`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the address is not necessarily 0x000AAc88. it can be a different address that is in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtoull()` with a base of 16 or `sscanf()` to convert from a hexadecimal number in ASCII to a wide-enough integer, and then convert that to a pointer.  Here, I use `strtoull()` for simplicity.

If your library implements it in a way that works for you, you might also use the `%p` format specifier to convert directly between pointers and their string representation.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEX_DIGITS_IN_PTR (sizeof(unsigned long long int)*2U)

int main(void)
{
  static const char msg[] = "hello, world!\n";
  char hex_address[HEX_DIGITS_IN_PTR] = {'\0'};

  snprintf( hex_address,
            sizeof(hex_address),
            "%llX",
            (unsigned long long int)(uintptr_t)(void*)&msg );

  const char* const converted_ptr =
    (void*)(uintptr_t)strtoull( hex_address, NULL, 16 );

  fputs( converted_ptr, stdout );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Once you’ve converted to a `char*`, you can do pointer arithmetic on it.

Your assumption that 8 hex digits are enough to hold a pointer will break in 64-bit code.  In this example, for brevity, I assume that an `unsigned long long int` is wide enough to store any pointer.  However, if you want to be as portable and future-proof as possible, you can use the constants in `<inttypes.h>` with `sscanf()`.  Alternatively, POSIX (and Linux) also provide width-restricted environments that guarantee that an `unsigned long` is wide enough to hold a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` to load the address to pointer.

```
char *p;
sscanf(add, "%08X", &p);
*p = 'a';
```

[Check the usage of sscanf here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: Do you mean `sscanf()`? Also, the assumption that 8 hex digits are enough breaks in 64-bit code.

Comment: This also will break if an `unsigned int` and a `char*` are different sizes.

Comment: @Davislor Good point, 64bit big endian environment will have such problems, should do more conversion.

Comment: Or if the high bits are initialized to garbage, since you don’t initialize the pointer to all-bits-zero.